The Pedometer from expo-sensors in react native does not work in the react-native-background-actions it does not watch any new steps
call of the function came from another file and here is some details:
  const options = {
    taskName: 'steps counter',
    taskTitle: 'Counting steps',
    taskDesc: 'Track your steps in the background',
    taskIcon: {
      name: 'ic_launcher',
      type: 'mipmap',
    },
    color: '#ff00ff',
    linkingURI: 'yourSchemeHere://chat/jane',
    parameters: {
      delay: 1000,
      dispatch,
      currentStepCount,
      pastStepCount,
      lastApiCallStep,
      setCurrentStepCount,
      setPastStepCount, 
      setSubscription,
      setIsPedometerAvailable,
      subscription
    },

the functional task(The Problem is here):
    import { Pedometer } from "expo-sensors";
    import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
    import { PermissionsAndroid, Platform } from "react-native";
    import BackgroundService from "react-native-background-actions";
    
    const sleep = (time) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
    
    const veryIntensiveTask = async (taskDataArguments) => {
      const {
        delay,
        dispatch,
        currentStepCount,
        pastStepCount,
        lastApiCallStep,
        setCurrentStepCount,
        setPastStepCount,
        setSubscription,
        setIsPedometerAvailable,
      } = taskDataArguments;
    
      console.log("Starting veryIntensiveTask with delay:", delay);
    
    
    
      // Keep the task running with the specified delay
      while (BackgroundService.isRunning()) {
    
    
        const subscribe = async () => {
    
          const isAvailable = await Pedometer.isAvailableAsync();
          console.log("Is Pedometer available:", isAvailable);
          setIsPedometerAvailable(String(isAvailable));
      
          if (isAvailable) {
            let newSubscription;
      
            if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
              const end = new Date();
              const start = new Date();
              start.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); // Set start time to 12 am
      
              const pastStepCountResult = await Pedometer.getStepCountAsync(start, end);
              if (pastStepCountResult) {
                setPastStepCount(pastStepCountResult.steps);
                console.log("Past step count for iOS:", pastStepCountResult.steps);
              }
      
              newSubscription = Pedometer.watchStepCount((result) => {
                setCurrentStepCount(result.steps);
                console.log("Current step count for iOS:", result.steps);
              });
            } else if (Platform.OS === "android") {
              newSubscription = Pedometer.watchStepCount((result) => {
                setCurrentStepCount(result.steps);
                console.log("Current step count:", result.steps);
              });
            }
      
            setSubscription(newSubscription);
          }
        
    
        }
    
        await subscribe();
    
        await sleep(delay);
      }
    };
    
    export default veryIntensiveTask;
    

does not work and this is wired, it pass the function do every thing correct but the newSubscription is the one that does not pass it,
in the app it works fine but in this function the interval task does not work,
